# How do you reset timers?

Tags: fallout-shelter, cheats

I tried out the clock setting cheat on a throw-away vault but somehow it also messed up my real one so now they both have 3000+ hours on radio station and 70d+ on returning wastelanders..

Any way to reset all the timers to default?

For some reason my phone refuses to change time at all anymore..

Comment: Have you ensured your clock is set right? Right date, right year?

Answer (score 5):

I use the time cheat every few days if I'm in need of something a dweller has collected from the wasteland. Here is how I fix most things, and the things that cannot be fixed- (hope this helps)

- Any resource room I rush- that way it immediately brings it to collection and the timer is reset. Even if it fails, the timer still gets reset.
- You'll notice that dwellers in the training rooms DO NOT need reset, their times stay static.
- Dwellers in the wasteland- I make sure that when I am in future time I either bring all dwellers back, OR leave them out there and when I come back to present time, then recall them. Either way- the time for wasteland explorers will become a bit screwy. This cannot be fixed :(
- ALSO- For wasteland explorers, say for example you fast forwarded time 24hrs. Then you bring time back to present. Once in the present if you send a dweller out into the wasteland, he or she WILL NOT collect any items for the first 24hrs (or how ever many hours into the future you had previously traveled). *On the bright side, they also will not take any health damage or radiation for that time period either. AND going into the second day of exploration they are more likely to find better items.
- Last but not least, the radio station- you CANNOT fix the radio station. If there is a way, I have not yet found it. (I haven't tried yet, but potentially if you take all the dwellers out of the room so that it is empty and then return them, or maybe replace them with others it might reset?)
- One glitch I found is that if you are attacked by deathclaws while in the future, and you return to the present, the deathclaws will still be in the same room- BUT the dwellers will not take any damage. They will also be stuck in battle for the full amount of time that you had time traveled. *this did not happen with the raiders. Only the deathclaws.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know too much about the time change affecting all vaults, as I'm not sure how the game keeps track of this information in order to apply it's formulas/calculations based on your phone's time. But...

For your wasteland explorer, you can hit recall and adjust your phone time past the amount of time it will take for them to arrive. Once you get back into the game, it should show your explorer waiting to be "Collected."

I don't believe there is a way to reset your radio station timer without destroying it and re-building. Though sometimes, with current game restrictions/conditions on destroying any particular building, even that is not an option. Another option you can also try is upgrading the radio station if it isn't fully upgraded yet.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward to a time when everything is ready  then do not click anything then exit out and set back to current date then all of the rooms will be ready and once you click them all they will be reset

Answer (score 1):

For wastelanders there's actually a 2nd cheat that can get you bunch of cool stuff. especially when you messed with the timer as much as 70days ahead.

to do that, first fast forward your time 70days ahead, so that you are able to call back all your wastelanders. Make sure everyone's back.

Next, go to Settings->Turn your date and time back to automatic setting 'on'. You might want to fully exit the game while doing this but I doubt there's any difference.

Send your wastelanders out to explore. Try to send those with maximum endurance and luck for maximum effect.
You will realize they will collect nothing nor lose any health after many days.
Now, back to Setting->turn your time and date setting 'off', then fast forward by 70-72days.

go back to the game and you will find your wastelanders having collected tonnes of cool weapons (above level 10)  and outfits which are highlighted in blue. you will be earning tonnes of caps as well, and your wastelanders will not have encountered any enemies.

This is the tricky part. to call back your wastelanders in the shortest time, after they have collected all those cool stuff, once again, go to setting, turn your clock back to 'automatic on'.
Return to the game and you will find that stuff collected remains there, but the explored time will be a few minutes, now recall your wastelanders and collect those items.

Not sure whether this works for everyone though. Now I have a population of 110 and all of them are equipped with weapons level 12 and above. deathclaws still attack my vault every 15-30min, but they hardly reach my 3rd level anymore.

Cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my experiments so far...,

If you do not collect your resources while in the future, when your return to normal time, they will still be tagged as ready and can be collected normally. The timer then is set for a few minutes after. Same goes for dwellers who are training (I believe, 90% certain)

Radio room is just as simple. Keep skiing forward in time until the radio room has a new person for you. Then return to normal time and collect them as above.

I am having the trouble with explorers who will not explore until they are past the time you fast forwarded to. It's been nearly a week since I've been able to send anyone out from that vault. My next series of experiments will involve me back tracking a few days, sending out the explorer, move forward a few days, recall him, and fast forward again back to normal time. It's very back to the future, but hopefully it will be more repeatable.

I'm a little afraid to try it, lest it delete all the dates I have in my calander, but I have an interesting plan. Mr handy can explore the wasteland  and not encounter any enemies and is quite safe for long exploration trips. My plan is to send Mr handy out, fast forward time 2 YEARS, recall, fast forward another year, collect, and return to normal time. 
If it works, it should get me a few hundred THOUSAND caps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fast forward to how many days left you have from the station.
2. When the icon is up from the station, don't click it.
3. Go back to your original time.
4. click the icon.

The timer for the radio station would be reset now.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone on IPhone what Jeeva has said is exactly the same WITH THE EXCEPTION that dwellers in training WILL need to be reset.

This is as simple as moving them from one training area to another, or to any other room, and then back to where they were training. Their training time will then begin to countdown from where it was before you moved them.

It may not be every dweller every time though. I had 4 dwellers training endurance and while three of them with timers less than 3 hours continued normally, another dweller with a timer of 18h 46m was stuck there until I moved her.

However, in another room where I had 6 dwellers training luck, they were all stuck, with timers ranging from 1h to 15h.

Answer (score -1):

About the radio station just remove all your dewllers from radio to residence, then adjust the time back to normal. U can also do the same with training room, well it work for me but idk about u guys, good luck :D